# PHP foreach reset and remove/subtract array values if condition is true

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

If I have following value, $result = 0, $request = 50 and $array = [25, 20], How do I reset and subtract $request value to 
$array values if $request value is greater than $array. and foreach will break if condition are
$request less than $array value or,  $request = 0 or, $array values = 0.

So condition like this and $result will be 5.

```
50      -    [25, 20]
|___   >=   __|    |
   25      00      |
   |_  >=  ________|
     5    00
```

**code:**

```
while(true) {
    $reset    = false
    $result   = 0;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($request >= $value) {
            ....
        } else {
            ....
            $reset = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$reset) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are thou using $result for?

Comment: $result was the subtracted value of $request and $arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request` will be same as `$result`, so it's the same thing and therefore not needed.

```
$request = 50;
$array = array(25, 20);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($request < $value || $request === 0 ) {
      break;
    }

    $request = $request - $value;
}

echo 'Result: '.$request;
```

**TESTS**

```
$request = 50;

$array = array(25, 20); 
// Result: 5

$array = array(25, 30); 
// Result: 25

$array = array(25, 25); 
// Result: 0

$array = array(51, 10);
// Result: 50
```

**EDIT**

Edit based on comments and OP fiddle.

```
$request = 50;
$array   = array(20, 25, 25);
$excess = max(array_sum($array) - $request, 0);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($request < $value || $request === 0 ) {
      $request = 0;
      break;
    }

    $request = $request - $value;
}


echo 'Result: '.$request.'<br />';
echo 'excessValue: '.$excess;
```

**TESTS**

```
$request = 50;

$array  = array(25, 20);
// Result: 5, excess: 0

$array = array(50, 20);
// Result: 0, excess: 20

$array   = array(52, 5);
// Result: 0, excess: 7

$array   = array(20, 25, 25);
// Result: 0, excess: 20
```

Comment: Is it possible whenever there's an array value loop will continue i.e $array = (10, 20, 30) or $array = array (28, 25, 10) ? until $request value becomes 0 or $request < $value.

Comment: Isn't it what it does right now? I'm not following. Whats desired result for `$array = array (28, 25, 10)`?

Comment: yes sir. there's a possibility I have several array values.

Comment: Can you give me examples and desired output?

Comment: Edited my answer and not have desired output and `$excess` variable too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
while(true) {
    $reset    = false;
    $result   = 0;
$request = 51;
$array = array(25, 20); 

foreach($array as  $value) {
    if($request>=$value){
        $request=$request-$value;
    }
    else{
    break;
            }
echo 'Result: '.$request;
    }
    if(!$reset) {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```